# AIX Openssl dgst hmac result differ

Tags: linux, openssl, sha1, aix, hmac

After a long search and tries, i m asking your help.

I'm trying to figure out why there is a different result between AIX environnement and other Linux environnement (CentOS for me) on executing the below command from a shell:

```
echo -n 37f3173afe3d73698a0d21e88f92gg38ABCDEFGINGRTSA221987327123test1529947146 | openssl dgst -sha1 -hmac 17fd3326gg375316228d18b55600848f
```

the result on a Centos 6 which is the attempted one is

> 7f3bc86e4193c8809de24ba66821c724f85bb1e8

the result on AIX 7.1 is

> 463eb074f3de44cb1b863153df74e7eb9c1d3b56

i don't know if it's relevant but if i remove "-n" from the echo on both environnements, the result is matching but obviously both false.

What did i miss?

Please, help me to figure it out this headache situation.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, `echo` isn't standardized, or rather it's standardized form is `printf`:

```
ksh@aix$ printf '%s' 37f3173afe3d73698a0d21e88f92gg38ABCDEFGINGRTSA221987327123test1529947146 |
         openssl dgst -sha1 -hmac 17fd3326gg375316228d18b55600848f

(stdin)= 7f3bc86e4193c8809de24ba66821c724f85bb1e8
```